# ¿Crear API o web Restful para obtener fecha y hora?

Tags: php, javascript, server

Estoy tratando de crear una API o web Restful en PHP que arroja la fecha y hora del servidor para aplicaciones locales o de escritorio y estos reciban la fecha con el enlace, el código para las aplicaciones de escritorio obtienen le fecha y hora con el protocolo NTP, si pongo el siguiente enlace en el código de la aplicación de escritorio, **0.pool.ntp.org** la aplicación recibe la fecha y hora correctamente, pero si ponga la dirección de la API que estoy creando (**https://fecha.enlace.com.mx**) no lo reconoce, entonces ¿requiere el enlace lanzar la fecha en algún formato? En el caso de que se requiera mandarlo con el protocolo NTP, ¿alguién tiene algún ejemplo?

Comment: el protocolo ntp va por udp puerto 123, mientras que https va por tcp puerto 443 si necesitas sincronizar aplicaciones con un ntp propio te conviene instalar un servidor ntp, hay un mini comohacerlo en https://askubuntu.com/a/14559/754957

Comment: Que has hecho hasta ahora? Puedes poner el código que responde al link de fecha.enlace.com.mx?

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @aloMalbarez He entendido que no se pueda crear un API como tal que arroje le fecha y hora y la aplicación lo reciba como NTP, si no que no son API´s como tal, si no servidores. Los mas recomendable sería arrojar una API que arroje esto en formato JSON y recibirla la información plana en la app

Comment: depende del uso que le vayas a dar, si es algo medianamente crítico y no confías en el reloj del sistema ( que debería sincronizarse via NTP y exponer la fecha y hora a la app ) tal vez que convenga mas incluir un cliente ntp en la app y te evitas tener que lidiar con los calculos de latencia via https